# SASS sprite url working but image not displayed

Tags: import, sprite, compass-sass, sass

I'm new at Compass and I'm very interested in the sprite generator. I see it works fine. I followed a tutorial and I'm having some problems with my sprite. I inserted the files inside the folder called `spr`. I already inserted the following code in the file screen.scss:

```
@import "spr/*.png";
```

And inserted the following for my header:

```
h1{
        @include spr-sprite(Flickr);
        height: 91px;
    }
```

I checked in inspector and the url is correct and the background position also. The problem is that once checked in the inspector element it cannot open the image url. The picture generated does work in the finder but its as the file doesnt exist. The name and location are perfect.

Could anybody let me know if they had this same problem and especially how to solve it?

**Edit: Generated CSS**

```css
.spr-sprite, header h1 {
    background: url('/images/spr-sbd3b4dd92d.png') no-repeat;
}
header h1 {
    background-position: 0 -120px; height: 91px;
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the page in your browser? Via `file://` or are you using a local server?

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like?  Did you enable `relative_assets` in your config.rb?

Comment: @steveax I was doing this via file://. After I tried also with MAMP to check if that was the error and still did not work. Is there a difference between between local file or local server for SASS

Comment: @cimmanon I'm using Scout. It generates automatically config.rb with relative_assets=true. In the CSS code I can see the loading of the sprite+the background position:                                        *                                                                   /* line 74, spr/*.png */
.spr-sprite, header h1 {
  background: url('/images/spr-sbd3b4dd92d.png') no-repeat;
}                                                                                                                   /* line 41, ../sass/screen.scss */
header h1 {
  background-position: 0 -120px;
  height: 91px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Scout, but...

Right now Sass is using *root relative* paths (leading slash). In order for those to resolve:

- You must be using a local server of some kind and loading the pages
  over http (`http://...` in the browsers url bar)
- The site must be at the root of the web folder (not in a sub folder)

For example:

```
├── css
│   └── site.css
├── images
│   └── spr-sbd3b4dd92d.png
├── index.html
└── sub-folder
    └── index.html
```

If you wish to have the site root in a subfolder, or be able to load the pages in a browser using the `file://` protocol, you should enable relative paths in config.rb:

```
relative_assets = true
```

If that is already uncommented (*viz:* no leading `#`) in your `config.rb` then Scout must not be paying any attention to the config file.

Looks like it might be [a bug in Scout](https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/46).